# Не работает функция PHP меньше или равно

Tags: php, html

Функция проверяет переменную, если она меньше или равна 10, то появляется класс unavailable, если нет, то visible. Но она почему-то не работает. Переменную $am_week_st беру через другой файл путем require_once. Ребят, помогите, пожалуйста, час уже сижу и не понимаю почему. При любом значении, выдает unavailable. С переменной все ок, в html она отображается

```
function getReward()
{
    if ($am_week_st <= 10)
        $result = 'unavailable';
    else
        $result = 'visible';
    return $result;
}

<div class="bnq1ym <?= getReward(); ?>">
```

Comment: "С переменной все ок," --- нет, не всё ок...

Comment: И что показывает `var_dump()` переменной `$am_week_st`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно изучить тему области видимости.  То, что вы подключили какой-то файл где есть переменная, никоим образом автоматически эту переменную внутрь функции не перекидывает. Функция - это отдельный "чёрный ящик", который ничего не знает ни о каких внешних переменных. Поэтому переменную надо передавать внутрь функции в качестве аргумента